# Nested anonymous function wont run (javascript)

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, arrow-functions, nested-function

I am trying to make a callback function that has an anonymous function nested inside. My code looks something like this:

```
    function submitGuess(guess) {
        if (guess.length === 5) {
            console.log("The guess was 5 letters");
            const postGuess = async () => {
                console.log("Anon function initiated")
                const res = await fetch(SOME_URL);
            }
        }
    }
    submitGuess(guess)
```

But the anonymous function never initiates. The second `console.log` never runs, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: The posted code defines but never invokes the nested function.  Somebody has to say `postGuess()`.  Note that, even after doing that, the value of `res`, the result of the fetch() will be discarded.

Comment: Where and how are you calling `submitGuess()`? Where and how are you calling `postGuess()`?

Comment: I have just updated the code. The submitGuess(guess) is called in the js file, but still, it won't run the anonymous code. I thought that by simply defining a cost to a anonymous function, it would run, but it still doesn't.

Comment: No. Defining a function does *define* it, not call it.

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER: THANKS FOR FEEDBACK

```
// declare the function
async function submitGuess(guess) {
    if (guess.length === 5) {
        console.log("The guess was 5 letters");
        const postGuess = async () => {
            console.log("Anon function initiated")
            const res = await fetch("url");
        };
        await postGuess(); // call the function
    }
}

submitGuess("input");
```

OLD:
Make sure you declare the functions then you call them !!

```
// declare the function
function submitGuess(guess) {
    if (guess.length === 5) {
        console.log("The guess was 5 letters");
        postGuess(); // call the function
    }
}

// declare the function
const postGuess = async () => {
    console.log("Anon function initiated")
    const res = await fetch(SOME_URL);
}

submitGuess(guess)
```

Comment: One needs to `await` the result of the asynchronous `postGuess` function within `submitGuess` which makes the latter an `async function` as well. But actually from the OP's original example code one does not know yet whether or where/when the OP wants to return the awaited `res` result.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't it not possible to declare and run anon function within another function?

Comment: @HanusáTjaldrafløtti ... of cause it is. And with your example code you show it's possible to declare/assign it. You just don't invoke/call/execute the `postGuess` function from within the `submitGuess` function's body.

Comment: I believe I have what you want now